# JavaScript not working on SelectList option

Tags: visualforce, javascript

[image]I have write a javascript method on SelectList Option

```
<apex:selectList id="IdSelectedMembers" value="{!selectedMemberIds}" multiselect="true" size="8" style="width: 200px;" ondblclick="OpenEvent(this.id);">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!selectedMemberOption}"/>                                                    </apex:selectList>
//-----JavaScript Method ----
function OpenEvent(sVal){    
    var sValue = document.getElementById(sVal).value;   
    alert(sValue);    
    var newwindow = window.showModalDialog("/apex/EventCalendar?id="+sValue, 'open page','_blank','scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
    newwindow.focus();
}
```

I got alert msg but new window not opening. can you help me.

Comment: this is a deprecated method. Why don't you just use `window.open()`

Comment: Which one `window.showModalDialog` or `window.open()`

Comment: @TusharSharma: please put your answer into answer, and not into comments

Comment: @Patlatus not sure if OP goes with my suggestion or change his approach. Anyway my answer is added. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @TusharSharma I have used window.open().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a deprecated method. You should use `window.open()` with same set of parameters

```
window.open("/apex/EventCalendar?id="+sValue, 'open page','_blank','scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
```